# redirect page by HyperLink1

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

Script

```
 function getParam(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if (results == null)
                return "";
            else
                return unescape(results[1]);
        }
```

HTML

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl="~/PersonPage/ConfighMessages.aspx?idCompany=javascript:getParam('idCompany');">bbb</asp:HyperLink>
```

i would like if `idCompany=123` in url onclikc this HyperLink  redirect to  `PersonPage/ConfighMessages.aspx?idCompany=123`

but this code redirect to:`/PersonPage/ConfighMessages.aspx?idCompany=getParam('idCompany');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javascript:getParam('idCompany')` is not going to work.

Try:

```
$("#HyperLink1").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "~/PersonPage/ConfighMessages.aspx?idCompany="+idCompany;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(<%= "#"+HyperLink1.ClientID %>).attr("href","/PersonPage/ConfighMessages.aspx?idCompany="+ getParam('idCompany'));
```

Or

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%= "~/PersonPage/ConfighMessages.aspx?idCompany=" + Request.QueryString["idCompany"]%>'>bbb</asp:HyperLink>
```